# How do I write the opposite of Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')? If user haven't got admin role return true

Tags: php, laravel

For example if I want to say, if one is not equal to two, do this, I'd write it like that.

```
if (1!=2){
    Do something
}
```

I'm trying to do the same with this `Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')`, however, I'm not sure I even can. Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Generally you want to ensure the `hasRole()` returns a boolean value or any result that could be resolved to true as a positive sign, then for the other case if it returns null, or false or other value resolvable to false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice the `!` sign.

```
if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')){
   #code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the operand not : `!`

> !Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')